# HTML page spilling over phone width

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple web page, and it seems to keep spilling over the width of the phone no matter what I try. I have tried to add the css attributes max-width:100% and overflow:hidden to every single container in the page, and still the problem remains.

I just feel like I am overlooking some very elementary solution. Could you please help?

Edit: A link to the page is https://www.hyperoffice.com/contact-us/contact-us.php

Comment: my program broke, it doesnt work, how do I fix it? based on this how do you expect somebody to help you? Provide your code, or an example of the problem that you are facing. Thanks

Comment: We need so code and/or examples. There is absolutely nothing we can do without that.

Comment: Apologies. I just added a link to the page.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Please add your css and html

Comment: Your link doesn't have an overflow issue, not on my iPhone at least. Post your code and a screenshot of your issue

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following to the main css file of your website.

```
body{
height: device-height;
width: device-width;
}
```

Cheers !